# How to change shutdown message?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

i wanted to know how to change the shutdown message when you're about to shutdown your computer, you know the "Goodbye, (username)" thing? Yea, that thing. How do i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the shutdown message unless you want to recompile `shutdown` program.

However, you can append your own message to the basic one :

```
shutdown 10 YOUR MESSAGE HERE
```

will output

```
The system is going down for maintenance in 10 minutes!
YOUR MESSAGE HERE
```

Comment: That's terminal, isn't it? I honestly don't wanna shutdown the machine via terminal. I want to do it the "casual" way, but it's not changebale so... how can I recompile it?